# bot to automatically access a website in corporate domain

Tags: http, dns, bots

There is a website in my corporate intranet, and I have to update info on it using IE6.0 frequently. the URL ends with `.asp`

I guess it is windows_domain-specialized, because when I open the URL in firefox, a dialog asks for username/password jumps out, which never appear when using IE6.

If I keyin username/passwd for logging into the corporate domain(say, my own PC), a webpage is uncompetely displayed, which is complete on IE6.

I can use a really little c,python,perl,html/javascript. but this situation is really beyond me without a kind hint.

so.. any good ideas? do I have to learn some winAPI for this, or shall I turn to autohotkey-like languages ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium IDE (a plugin for firefox) it will record what you want to do and you can play it back automatically. It will also generate code to run it in any language.

Download it Here: http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: thanks, but I cannot use firefox to access its function, even with username/passwd in http request http://username:passwd@URL  .. thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, you can use Selenium RC from C# or VB.net to control internet explorer. Just don't get the nice plug-in, you will have to code it by hand. You can also take a look at WatIN. Might be easier to use.